# Using old MacBook battery as an USB charger. Known adapters/cases?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, battery

I have an old MacBook with an OK battery.
When I go out sailing or traveling I have a lead battery with me to be able to charge USB-things. iPhone, portable speakers, etc.

The old MacBooks battery is a lithium battery with excellent power density. I would like to use that instead. Have you heard about an adapter or a case that lets you take a MackBook battery and get one or several USB outlets?

Charging of the MacBook battery is not needed since I can do that in my old Mac.

Think the MacBook is 2007-ish. It's from when the batteries were easily removable with a coin anyways.

Comment: Have you considered using the old mac book that came with the battery?

Comment: Yep. That's not gonna work since it is somewhat taken apart into pieces. Would alos like a smaller solution.